# How to point tools.jar in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

I'm encountering this issue regarding a `tools.jar` in Spring Tool Suite. It seems that it has already enumerated where it checked for the said jar. Fortunately, I was able to find where it is located but I can't figure out how to tell Spring Tool Suite where it can be found. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is a screen shot of the error message:
[image]

Comment: Install the latest version of JDK 1.8 in your system then restart and try again.

Comment: I did this for a couple of times (the restart), but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to install a regular JDK on your system and then point Eclipse/STS at this JDK in the SpringToolSuite4.ini file (aka eclipse.ini), as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

This will let your IDE run on that JDK and the tools.jar will be found automatically.